# Change text back and forth on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is some little miss understanding of how can the text of element be changed back after it was already mutated ?

```js
$('.target').click(function() {
  
  

  if($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
    $(this).text('ORIGINAL').toggleClass('clicked');
  }

  $(this).text('CLICKED').toggleClass('clicked');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='target'>ORIGINAL</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the original in jQuery's data store, and then get it back

```js
$('.target').each(function() {
    
    $(this).data('original', $(this).text());
    
}).on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked').text(function(_, txt) {
        var org = $(this).data('original');
    
        return txt === org ? 'CLICKED' : org;
    });
});
```

```css
.clicked {color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="target">Click</div>
<br/>
<div class="target">Click</div>
<br/>
<div class="target">Click</div>
<br/>
<div class="target">Click</div>
<br/>
<div class="target">Click</div>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You last line of code is triggered everytime you click. And it sets the text to *CLICKED*.

You just need to use `else` statement.

```js
$('.target').click(function() {

  if($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
    $(this).text('ORIGINAL').toggleClass('clicked');
  } else {
    $(this).text('CLICKED').toggleClass('clicked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='target'>ORIGINAL</a>
```